# neo4j improving cypher query performance

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have `items` graph db. each `item` is connected to multiple `properties`, which can be shared by multiple `items`.
I add a `search` node which is defined by few `properties`.

So I have (search_node) connected to multiple (properties_nodes) connected to multiple (items_nodes)

Now I would like to get a list of items who answer this search by {x} properties or more. Ordered by number of matching properties.

```
start se=node:node_auto_index(name = {name}), pr = node:node_auto_index(type="item_property")
MATCH p=(se) -[rt:SEARCH]- > (pr)<-[r]-(item)
WHERE Has(item.type) and (item.type = "item")
WITH item, collect(distinct pr.name) as rs
where length(rs) > {x}
RETURN item.name as item_name, length(rs) as matching_properties
ORDER BY  matching_properties desc
```

The performance issue for me, is that it will search for all matching items, even those who match for only one property, and then remove all the items who are matching less than {x}.
If {x} is higher than 1, it's a big waste.

How can I "MATCH" only by {x} matching properties?

Created a matching sample : http://console.neo4j.org/?id=adrgsh

(neo4j version 1.9.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO to be able to match only items with > x properties, you still need to find all those items that have properties in common with the search node. Post that, you can filter out the matches with < x properties in common. What kind of numbers are you getting? In your worst case, how many items were matched and how many were discarded?

You can simplify your query (matched results on the console but it could be missing some details that are not specified in this question)

```
START se=node(11) 
MATCH (se)-[:SEARCH]- >(pr)<-[:HAS]-(item) 
WHERE HAS (item.type) AND (item.type = "item") 
WITH count(pr) AS matching_properties, item 
WHERE matching_properties>1 
RETURN item.name AS item_name, matching_properties 
ORDER BY matching_properties DESC
```

Comment: For now, I'm testing on a dataset of 5000 items. for some 'searches', I can have 500 that answer one property but only 50 that answer 2 properties or more. 
This statistics is bad for me. If I scale it up it will have bad performance, cause usually I need more than one matching property.

Comment: I agree with Luanne, can you test Luannes query suggestion on a large enough dataset and see how it performs?

Comment: Right now, I'm running on an EC2 Micro instance, a really 'weak' machine. So even a query on a 5000 dataset, takes between 3 - 4 sec. I'm using neo4j for node js to query the DB...

Comment: Both queries return in the same time?

Comment: This improvement did enhanced the performance by 0.5sec to 1 sec. Unfortunately, the performance keeps on changing from several technical reasons but it's still slow. If the definite answer is that I can't restrict the "MATCH" part of the search, to only those items who match {x} properties of the search, then I would approve this answer.

Comment: No you cannot instruct the match in that manner. However you might want to examine your model and/or provide more info in another question