# cypher query match on an optional node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to improve an already published query : 
[neo4j improving cypher query performace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935393/neo4j-improving-cypher-query-performace)

Again, I have `items` graph db. each `item` is connected to multiple `properties`, which can be shared by multiple `items`. 
BUT , this time I want to search for `items` starting with few `property` nodes and finding the most connected items.

So, I have a set of properties `pr=["pr1","pr2","pr3"]` and I want to find the most related `items`

i.e.

```
match (pr)-[r]-(item)
return item, count(r) as matching_properties
order by matching_properties
```

But, I want to find similar items too. There are `SIMILAR` relationships between `properties`, and I want to find:

```
MATCH (pr) -[:SIMILAR]->(pr2)-[r]-(item)
```

I tried retrieving all items by doing:

```
MATCH (pr) -[r*1..2]-(item)
```

The problem is that I want only the paths that got with a `SIMILAR` relationship through a `property` node, and unfortunately I have a lot of paths through some other nodes with other relationships.
So I can do Something like :

```
MATCH (pr) -[r*1..2]-(item)
where (length(r)= 1 or ANY (x in r where (type(x)="SIMILAR")))
```

but that's really not efficient because it's only a small portion of the paths.
I really would want to do an optional matching similar to this :

```
MATCH (pr) -[r2?:SIMILAR]->(pr2?)-[r]-(item)
where pr2.type = "property"
```

Or, using an "OR" operand between the two path options (which I know that it doesn't exist..)

Is there any way to do that?
Currently I'm using neo4j 1.9.2 but I am planning to move to 2.0.
So an answer for 2.0 would be good for me too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

Paths starting at 0 (`*0..`) also include the zero length path to the start-node.

```
MATCH (pr:property)-[:SIMILAR*0..1]->(pr2:property)<-[:HAS_PROPERTY]-(item:item)
RETURN pr2, item
```

Comment: That's what I wanted - it gives all the items similar/non similar.